# Called AE Title Not Recognised error in echoscu

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I was trying to test the connectivity of dcmqrscp.
I have used the following command for starting dcmqrscp.

`dcmqrscp --config C:\Dicom\config\dcmqrscp.cfg`

Please find the below config file that I used.

```
NetworkTCPPort  = 11113
MaxPDUSize      = 16384
MaxAssociations = 16

HostTable BEGIN

acme1           = (ACME1, localhost, 1234) 
acme2           = (ACME2, localhost, 5678)
acmeCTcompany   = acme1, acme2

HostTable END

VendorTable BEGIN

"Acme CT Company"   = acmeCTcompany

VendorTable END

AETable BEGIN

ACME_STORE   C:\Dicom\echo   RW (100, 1024mb)   acmeCTcompany

AETable END
```

I've created C:\Dicom\echo as well before running the dcmqrscp command.
The following echoscu command was used to test the connectivity of dcmqrscp: 
`echoscu -d localhost 11113 -aec ACME_STORE -aet ACME1`

But I am getting the following error:

```
D: $dcmtk: echoscu v3.6.0 2011-01-06 $
D:
D: Request Parameters:
D: ====================== BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-RQ =====================
D: Our Implementation Class UID:      1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.0
D: Our Implementation Version Name:   OFFIS_DCMTK_360
D: Their Implementation Class UID:
D: Their Implementation Version Name:
D: Application Context Name:    1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
D: Calling Application Name:    ACME1
D: Called Application Name:     ACME_STORE
D: Responding Application Name: resp. AP Title
D: Our Max PDU Receive Size:    16384
D: Their Max PDU Receive Size:  0
D: Presentation Contexts:
D:   Context ID:        1 (Proposed)
D:     Abstract Syntax: =VerificationSOPClass
D:     Proposed SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Proposed Transfer Syntax(es):
D:       =LittleEndianImplicit
D: Requested Extended Negotiation: none
D: Accepted Extended Negotiation:  none
D: Requested User Identity Negotiation: none
D: User Identity Negotiation Response:  none
D: ======================= END A-ASSOCIATE-RQ ======================
I: Requesting Association
D: Constructing Associate RQ PDU
F: Association Rejected:
F: Result: Rejected Permanent, Source: Service User
F: Reason: Called AE Title Not Recognized
```

One of my observation:In normal echoscu operations,the data dictionary is loaded  correctly.But in the above logs of echoscu,we couldn't find any data dictionary load operations.

Could you please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will extend my comment, as this might be helpful in the future. I think that the following scenario results from incorrect hosts configuration, unfortunately I cannot check this now.

When echoscu connects to dcmqrscp, the latter receives association with the following parameters: `callingPresentationAddress`, `callingAPTitle`, `calledAPTitle`. First parameter is just the unique host address of echoscu.

If **both echoscu and dcmqrscp run in the same Windows machine**, `callingPresentationAddress` is set to value of the `hostname`. The value can be obtained by `ipconfig /all` in the section `Windows IP Configuration`:

```
>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration 
  Host Name . . . . . . : MY_PC
  Primary DNS Sufix . . :
  Node Type . . . . . . : Hybrid
  IP Routing Enabled. . : No
(...)
```

The same value should be set in dcmrscp's config file in HostTable section:

```
HostTable BEGIN
acme1           = (ACME1, MY_PC, 1234) 
(...)
HostTable END
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you also make sure that the directory C:\Dicom\echo is writable? Does it work if you change "acmeCTcompany" (last column in your "AE Table") to "ANY"? In any case, I would also start the dcmqrscp with -d (--debug) in order to see more details.

Comment: Yes I got the result correctly when I tried ANY .But Could you please explain why it happends. I just gave the correct AE Title name

Comment: Just checked your configuration with the DCMTK 3.6.2 version of dcmqrscp and echoscu - it works. Did you really call "echoscu" from "localhost"? What does dcmqrscp say in --debug mode?

Comment: I have reproduced the error of OP.  Hostname of scu was not "localhost" but "MY_PC". Indeed --debug said `Association Received (MY_PC:ACME1 -> ACME_STORE)`. The solution is to update HostTable section.

Comment: Thanks Reismeier andBartlomiej.It works when I changed the localhost with my PC name .It also works when I add ANY as the peer name instead of  acmeCTcompany