# Incorrect received value callingPresentationAddress in dcmqrscp under Windows

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

**TL;DR**:

When I run `dcmqrscp` under Windows 7 x64 (official current 3.6.2 binaries), the server does not recognize IP of incoming `echoscu` clients. Instead the value of `callingPresentationAddress` is set to `www` or `name_of_localhost`, depending on the ethernet interface, by which the connection is associated.

**Full description**

The content of `dcmqrscp` config file:

```
NetworkTCPPort  = 11113
MaxPDUSize      = 16384
MaxAssociations = 16
HostTable BEGIN

archive = (ARCHIVE, localhost, 11113)
client1 = (CLIENT1, 146.147.51.82, 12345)
client2 = (CLIENT2, www, 12345)
clients = client1, client2
HostTable END

AETable BEGIN
ARCHIVE   c:/tmp/dcm   RW (100, 1024mb)   clients
AETable END
```

I connect to the server from Debian machine on 145.146.51.82:

```
echoscu -d 146.147.51.30 11113 -aec ARCHIVE -aet CLIENT1
```

Output of the server is as below:

```
D: $dcmtk: dcmqrscp v3.6.2 2017-07-14 $
D: 
D: setting network send timeout to 60 seconds
D: setting network receive timeout to 60 seconds
D: PDU Type: Associate Request, PDU Length: 205 + 6 bytes PDU header
(...)
D: Parsing an A-ASSOCIATE PDU
I: Association Received (www:CLIENT1 -> ARCHIVE)
D: Parameters:
D: ====================== BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-RQ =====================
(...)
D: ======================= END A-ASSOCIATE-RQ ======================
D: Peer www:CLIENT1 is not not permitted to access ARCHIVE (see configuration file)
I: Refusing Association (BadAEService)
```

If I switch calling AE of `echoscu` to `CLIENT2`, the answer is positive. This is because of the line in config file `client2 = (CLIENT2, www, 12345)`

If `echoscu` is run from the same Windows machine, instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, the value of `callingPresentationAddress` is `name_of_localhost`. This issue was described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48654474/7708542).

In the opposite direction (`echoscu` at Windows, `dcmqrscp` at Debian) everything is correct:

```
Association Received (146.147.51.30:CLIENT1 -> ARCHIVE)
```

I suspect that the problem is related to wrong configuration of my Windows, but I have no idea how I should fix it.

Comment: I guess there is a reason for the following comment both in the sample configuration file "dcmqrscp.cfg" and in the documentation "dcmqrcnf.txt": "NOTE: in the current implementation you cannot substitute an IP address for a hostname."

Comment: OK, than you for pointing that, so the new question would be, how to map Presentation Address to IP? And still there is unresolved issue, why the address is "www"?

Comment: I guess that "www" is the hostname that is associated with your IP address (mapped by calling the hostname lookup function of your operating system). You can find the corresponding DCMTK code in receiveTransportConnectionTCP() and should be able to disable this lookup by starting dcmqrscp with option -dhl.

Comment: OK, now I see that there is a problem with my OS configuration. I will have to figure it out. Anyway, `-dhl` allows me to use IP adresses. Would you like to write an answer to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a hostname is associated with the IP address of the system connecting to the dcmqrscp (either locally or by a corresponding entry to the DNS), this hostname is used to match against the hostname specified in the "HostTable" section of the configuration file. If this hostname lookup is not available (or disabled by dcmqrscp's option -dhl), the IP address is used instead. This might not be very intuitive but as far as I know has never changes over the last 20 + x years (or so).

See documentation in [dcmqrcnf.txt](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/file_dcmqrcnf.html) for details.